# Sources of cabinet-making apprentices in Ireland around 1815-1830?

Tags: ireland, 1820s, 1810s, apprenticeship-records

My great-great-grandfather Charles Frazer, a 'wild Irish republican' according to family folklore, was a master cabinet-maker in Tasmania. He was very cagey about his roots about which nothing reliable is currently known. If I could find records relating to his apprenticeship, possibly in Ireland, that would be a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have lucked out on this search.  I found this book:  Irish Furniture: Woodwork and Carving in Ireland from the Earliest Times to ...

A quick look in the appendix shows an alphabetical listing of Irish cabinet makers; some in the 1700's.  The actual book looks pretty interesting; I might get one for myself.

You can find out more about the book a preview here:   https://books.google.ca/books?id=gL4d2gitz2oC&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=Cabinet+Maker+apprenticeship+records+-+Ireland&source=bl&ots=uqbSLBHG-S&sig=ACfU3U0dqbkpBedICSeIkd34AC-DrDlyLQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjuqviN_rbpAhUKmeAKHZrTDWEQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Cabinet%20Maker%20apprenticeship%20records%20-%20Ireland&f=false

The site says the book is available from Amazon and Chapters.Indigo

Comment: This looks very useful so I've ordered it, although it's a hefty journey to Australia. Thanks very much! Of course, it may not include those who've successfully finished an apprenticeship with the listed cabinetmakers - too much to hope for, I think, that my guy may have been separately listed before he emigrated to Tasmania, but you never know. It's a valuable lead, at least. It's also possible that he may have trained in Aberdeen (his father was Scottish) but I now hope, thanks to your efforts, that there's a similar book available for Scotland.

Comment: @ JMK, I've found that internetarchive.org has been a awesome site for downloading all kinds of these type books among so many others genealogy and history related.  You might wish to do a search through their site before forking out the cash to retailers.  They download many different formats as well.  I'll keep my eye out.  :)  Here's a link to a guide you might find useful, but look for tomes in the free places first:  https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/apprentices-and-masters/

Comment: @ JMK, Here is a resource for records in Scotland:  https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/research/guides/crafts-and-trades

Comment: These three suggestions are excellent, SDoS - and, no doubt, they'll help many others on similar quests to find lost forebears via guild-trade records. Deep gratitude.